# Trying to track a PID in windows created from the pub command

Tags: command-line, bash, dart

I am doing some Polymer and Dart development, and when I am running the server, i run `pub serve` in order to spin up the server.  The issue is that to stop the server, i need to break out of it `<ctrl + c>`.  This is a two part question.

The first is:  If i want to detach a process from a command prompt, can i just append a `&` at the end and it will run itself just like when using unix systems?

The second question is:   Is there a way to get the PID of the spun up server, via `pub` or `pub serve` in order to kill it when I am done using it?  I wasn't sure if it would pass an ID that i could use.

I have been trying different approaches using pub and I wasn't getting any sort of identifier.  I was also looking in the command prompt for processes which look like the server, but when using `tasklist` but the Image Name and Session Name were not really discriptive enough to help me determine what is the executed pub server.  It looks like it might be just a stack of tasks.... which means the bottom are near the ones i would want.

I do see a tasklist.exe from just execution, and then right before it i see a *dart.exe* file.  Now, that is the process i am fairly certain, since i dont use dart on this machine outside of using it through pub.  I just dont see any flags, in case there are multiple dart programs running as my plan will entail, 2 of which are just processing servers.

I was looking up the `start` command which seems to be what i am sort of looking for, when it comes to having a non-shell-reliant program.  http://ss64.com/nt/start.html  I was looking into:

```
start "testprogram" /b "pub" serve
```

it looked like i was suppose to put pub in quotes and works, but it works without too.

I still dont see any ways to find it in the tasklist, as i was hoping to see "testprogram" somewhere, there or somewhere else.

Comment: `tasklist | findstr -i pub` should find it ...

Comment: Just tested the command, and didnt work.  When running it, it calls dart.exe, so if i did something like `tasklist | findstr -i dart` that works, but i cant tell which is which if i have say 2 or 3 different dart executions running.    I hoped there was a way that `start` would return a PID or some other flag we can search on.  I really wish the *Title* was a queryable flag, then i just create custom titles, but the title doesnt appear in the tasklist by default.

Comment: Look at `wmic process call create ...` it returns a PID. I tried `wmic process call create notepad`. Maybe that will meet your needs.

Comment: `wmic process call create "start 'myTest' /b pub serve"` returned `Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 9;
};` which doesnt make sense as a relevant PID i can use to kill the process.

Comment: Hmm. I got `Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 6284;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};`

Comment: What happens if you run `wmic process call create "pub serve"?

Comment: also creates a ReturnValue of 9.   called:  `wmic process call create "pub serve"`

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you.  Ill keep looking as well.  Its weird that it returns 9.  I have no idea why it returned that number multiple times.  Seems like something with wmic and pub dont quite work well or something

Comment: return value 9 is `Path not found`. Can you try with the full path to `pub`?

Comment: Got the path, called the following: `wmic call create start "C:\code\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub serve"` and it said invalid format: *Hint: <paramlist> = <param> [, <paramlist> ]*, and if i called it with *pub.bat* it says: *call - Alias not found.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38296/discussion-between-davidpostill-and-fallenreaper).

Comment: <sigh> What you are attempting to do won't work. You didn't tell us that `pub` was a batch file. You need to get the PID of the command run **inside the batch file**. That is next to impossible for me to figure out with having the software on my machine. Good luck ;)

Comment: I cracked open the bat file to peek inside.  What is in there isnt bad.  I might be able to work with it, since I can always tweak some things here and there.  Most of it is doing setters such as paths, options etc.  Then there is a line which sounds like the process at hand:   `"%BIN_DIR%\dart" %VM_OPTIONS% "%BIN_DIR%\snapshots\pub.dart.snapshot" %*` which makes sense as to why i see ***tasklist*** showing me dart.exe in the list.