# does start title and tasklist /fi windowtitle reference the same title?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I was looking up the `start` and `tasklist` commands, and i noticed 2 things.  They both had references to a window title.

```
start "myTest" /b somefile argA
tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq myTest"
```

the thing that confuses me is that the task list isnt returning any matches to me.  Is there something i am doing wrong, or do these not reference the same *title*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They sure do refer to the same title. It is the title that appears within the top border of your window. The problem is your START /B switch causes the process to be launched within the same console window, and a window can only have one title. START does not change the title of the window if the /B switch is used.

Run your START command with the /B switch, and you will see that your window title does not change.

Now run the START command without /B and you will see a new window with the correct title. Your TASKLIST command will now find the correct process.

Comment: maybe start then is not the command I want?    I am trying to launch somefile as a passive process, not needing a command line.  I want to launch it and then carry on with the script, while still have a pointer / PID to the process so i can kill it later?    It is then possible to do something like:  `start "myTest" somefile argA &` like in unix to break the console-process dependancy?

Comment: That only seems to work if the command you are starting is actually a `cmd` shell. `start "testprogram" "notepad"` followed by `tasklist /v | findstr -i testprogram` does not find anything.

Comment: See [Trying to track a PID in windows created from the pub command](http://superuser.com/q/1064578) and comments for the background to this question. We have been puzzling over it all afternoon :;

Comment: @DavidPostill - I believe a more generic way of stating the issue is - Not all programs allow you to set the window title via the START command. Many programs override any value that START tries to establish.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try for this example to start `Chrome.exe` and kill all its PID(s) after launching it !

```
@echo off
set MyProcess=Chrome.exe
start "" %MyProcess%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "TOKENS=2" %%a in ('tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %MyProcess%"') do (
    Set PID=%%a & echo The PID of %MyProcess% = !PID! 
    Echo( & Echo To Kill all PID of "%MyProcess%" , just Hit any key & pause 
    Taskkill /PID !PID! /F /T
)
EndLocal
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

you can easily check for the Pid from your Process you are looking for and kill them later anytime if needed with

```
 taskkill /pid %PID%
```

keep in mind that you need the double space after Administator if you search for an cmd process.

Here an fully example how to use it:

https://gist.github.com/robinrm/ecd1ceb1fc295b2e7b125ca82f42cafe

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1776858/edit) your answer to explain how exactly does this address the question OP asked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).